# Pass additional data with Yii2 form via ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

I have the following ajax call to submit a Yii2 form:

```
var form = $("#purchase-order-form");
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: form.serialize(),   
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
         $('#modal').modal('hide');
         callNotify(data);
     }
});
```

This works fine, however I have additional data that I need to pass along with the form's data. It is a string with json encoding, that I created calling `JSON.stringify` in an array created by me.

I tried to use `.serializeArray()` instead of `.serialize()` and push the additional content to the form, like this:

```
var form = $("#purchase-order-form");
var table-data = tableToJson('.products-table');
var data = form.serializeArray();     
data.push({table: table});

$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    data: data,   
    type: 'post',
    success: function(data) {
         $('#modal').modal('hide');
         callNotify(data);
     }
});
```

When I see the console, the content is at the end of the array, but in my Controller it is passed as undefined.

I think yii processes data that is not from the model before letting me load it.

How can I pass data along with the form while still being able to load the model using `$model->load()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add the extra data with `name` and `value` indexes, where `name` holds the name of the variable to be posted and `value` is the value of the variable you want to append

`{name: 'data', value: data}`

But before i suggest the actual code you have a few things to look after, you cannot name a variable containing `-` like you have declared `var table-data = tableToJson('.products-table');`

> Hyphens can be mistaken as subtraction attempts. Hyphens are not
>   allowed in JavaScript names.

Then you are assigning `data.push({table: table});` whereas there is no variable with the name `table`.

So your complete code should be like

```
var form = $("#purchase-order-form");
    var tableData = tableToJson('.products-table');
    var data = form.serializeArray();     
    data.push({name: 'table', value:tableData});

    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        data: data,   
        type: 'post',
        success: function(data) {
             $('#modal').modal('hide');
             callNotify(data);
         }
    });
```